# Howto cast List items from VBox.getChildren() in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, casting, children

I have a `VBox` in which many nodes of type `Button`are added.

```
private final VBox vbox = new VBox();

private final Button b1= new Button("1");
private final Button b2= new Button("2");
private final Button b3= new Button("3");
private final Button b4= new Button("4");

vbox.getChildren().addAll(b1,b2,b3,b4);
```

Is there a way to cast its child items to `Button` type.

I need something like this:

```
ObservableList<Button> children = (ObservableList<Button>) vbox.getChildren();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible, if you use the raw type.

```
ObservableList<Button> children = (ObservableList)vbox.getChildren();
```

Note however, that this can easily lead to `ClassCastException`s at runtime, if the types are incorrect or the child list hardcodes the parameter type for a parameter that depends on the type parameter.

Comment: Sweet! I tried so many different approaches but none has worked this far but yours. Thanks a ton for your time, Fabian!